# Update Native Android app with Ionic Android app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, app-update

I have a native Android app with base version. (ie. Ver 1.0) 
I want update this native Android App with Ionic Android App. (ie Ver 1.1)
Is it possible to update a native Android app with Ionic Android App?
I've tried it. But it says "**INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE**".
Can someone help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to update native app with ionic app. You have to keep in mind following things to achieve this: -

1. Package name of the apps should be exactly similar.
2. Version code of ionic app (new app) should be greater than old native app.
3. Keystore used for signing both the apps, should be similar.

IMO if you follow all the above points, you can update the application.

Comment: Also the app must be consistent with the policy of Google Play

Comment: @Prashant Sable Thank you for quick update. Will check and confirm.